# Run RASA with flask

Tags: flask, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I want to run RASA with --enable-api inside the python code rather than the command line. Below is my code which is not working. Let me know how can i do that. The issue is once i hit the service because the channel is 'cmdline' it comes to the command line. I don't know how to resolve this.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging
import rasa_core
from rasa_core.agent import Agent
from rasa_core.policies.keras_policy import KerasPolicy
from rasa_core.policies.memoization import MemoizationPolicy
from rasa_core.interpreter import RasaNLUInterpreter
from rasa_core.utils import EndpointConfig
from rasa_core.run import serve_application
from rasa_core import config

from rasa_core.policies.fallback import FallbackPolicy
from rasa_core.policies.keras_policy import KerasPolicy

from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@app.route("/conversations/default/respond",methods=['POST'])
def run_weather_bot(serve_forever=True):
    logging.basicConfig(level="ERROR")
    interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter('C:\\xxxx_nlu\\models\\nlu\\default\\weathernlu')
    action_endpoint = EndpointConfig(url="http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:5055/webhook")
    agent = Agent.load('C:\\xxxx_nlu\\models\\dialogue', interpreter=interpreter, action_endpoint=action_endpoint)

    rasa_core.run.serve_application(agent,channel='cmdline')

    return agent


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run("xxx.xx.xx.xxx",5005,debug=True)
```

Comment: which Rasa version are you using?

Comment: RASA 0.12.2 version

Comment: Can you switch Rasa `1.1.x`? It's way newever and things should be easier there (also you are safe for the future then)

Comment: @Tobias ya but how can i run using Flask programtically rather than command line.

Comment: `1.x` uses `Sanic` as server. For future compatibility of your code, I'd recommend to switch. Also what you are doing above is also also already done and accessible via https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/your-own-website/#rest-channels . I don't exactly see the use of the custom code.

Comment: @Tobias ya i am planning to but in the document i can't find any python implementation of it. Can you share me any links if available ?

Comment: what do you need the python implementation for? Does this documentation help you https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/jupyter-notebooks/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling rasa bot in the command line in your ***run_weather_bot*** function using below command.

> rasa_core.run.serve_application(agent,channel='cmdline')

As you can see its serving as command line application.

I have made some changes in your code for a conversation with rasa chatbot. You can refer [AGENT](https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/core/api/agent/) documentation and [Weather bot](https://medium.com/coinmonks/rasa-python-weather-chatbot-51fc218d346d) article for connection of RASA agent and how RASA agent handles the input message.

```
def rasa_agent():
    interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter("Path for NLU")
    action_endpoint = EndpointConfig(url="Webhook URL")
    agent = Agent.load('Path to Dialogue', interpreter=interpreter, action_endpoint=action_endpoint)
    ## Next line runs the rasa in commandline
    # rasa_core.run.serve_application(agent,channel='cmdline') 
    return agent

@app.route("/conversations/default/respond",methods=['POST'])
def run_weather_bot(serve_forever=True):

    agent = rasa_agent() # calling rasa agent
    ## Collect Query from POST request
    ## Send Query to Agent
    ## Get Response of BOT
    output = {} ## Append output
    return jsonify(output)
```